# How to iterate through an object array and pass those values outside of the foreach loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

This probably won't be my clearest question but here we go. I have a class that instantiates an object. This object runs through a series of methods and calls up some values from a web services dll. Here is my issue. The two strings that get pulled into the object array have to be looped through via a foreach in order to pass them through another method.

I am at a loss as to how to capture the results of the foreach loop and pass them outside the loop so I can process them.

Essentially, I am trying to loop through an array of objects and single out each object in the foreach loop and then I want to pass these two objects out so that I can pass them into methods.

I am able to type each object into a string, concatenate the string, and pass the string outside to the loop. I then can us the split method to split up the strings but they are now strings and no-longer objects so my methods no longer work. I am at my wits end here and any advice would be awesome...

Here is the code excerpt in question

```
JciFqr objRootFqr = objClient.CreateFqr("SIPE-NAE-001", "Programming.CommonPath", JciFqr.Classifications.Folder, JciFqr.Types.Folder);

JciFqr[] aobjRoomFqrs = await objClient.GetObjectsAsync(objRootFqr, CancellationToken.None);

foreach(JciFqr objFqr in aobjRoomFqrs)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(objFqr);
    JciFqr objCodeFqr = JciFqr.Create(objFqr, "Code_Blue", JciFqr.Classifications.Object, JciFqr.Types.BinaryValue);
    await objClient.WritePropertyAsync(objCodeFqr, "Present Value", a_bOn ? "on" : "off", CancellationToken.None);
    System.Console.WriteLine(objCodeFqr);

    //await objClient.ReadPropertyAsync(objCodeBlueFqr, "Present Value", a_bOn ? "on" : "off", CancellationToken.None);
    var obj = objCodeFqr ;
    fqrs = obj + "|" + fqrs;

    count++;
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.WriteLine(fqrs);

string[] fqrArray = fqrs.Split('|');
for (int i = 0; i < fqrArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fqrArray[i]);
}

string strStatus = "";
string uri1 = fqrArray[0];
string uri2 = fqrArray[1];

bool triggerCodeBlue = false;

Console.WriteLine("Trigger the Code");
triggerCodeBlue = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Step 1: format your code properly

Comment: I am curious ... what is a "Fqr" the abbreviation of or acronym for :D

Comment: Fully Qualified Reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before your loop, make a `List` to store your objects:

```
List<JciFqr> fqrs = new List<JciFqr>();
```

Inside your loop, store the object in the list:

```
fqrs.Add(objCodeFqr);
```

After the loop, you can access `fqrs[0]` and `fqrs[1]`, or loop through it with another `foreach`.

Comment: Freaking Beautiful, thanks. I'm learning C# as I go coming from a purely LAMP background

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand the code, but from the description in the question it seems it could also be a case to use the keyword "yield"

the yield function allows you to return values from a loop, one by one and turn those results into an enumerable, for example:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Combinations(string input){
    for(int i=0;i<input.length-1; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<input.length; j++){
            yield return input[i].ToString() + input[j].ToString();
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (string output in Combinations("abc")){
        Console.WriteLine(output); //outputs "ab", "ac", "bc"
    }
}
```

yielding results is algorithmically speaking, the same thing as adding them to a list and returning the list, but can use significantly less memory when you yield a lot of results.

Comment: I can't type the values to a string though, they have to stay as the object or it breaks the methods.

Comment: you can yield results of any type, the code with the strings is just an example

Comment: the difference is that your function will produce an IEnumerable<YourObjectType> rather than IEnumerable<string>

Answer (score 0):

There is also yield return inside your foreach loop.  I'm guessing on the types since they are ohh so clear.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<JciFqr, JciFqr>> GetStuff() {
    foreach(JciFqr objFqr in aobjRoomFqrs){
        JciFqr objCodeFqr = JciFqr.Create(objFqr, "Code_Blue", JciFqr.Classifications.Object, JciFqr.Types.BinaryValue);
        await objClient.WritePropertyAsync(objCodeFqr, "Present Value", a_bOn ? "on" : "off", CancellationToken.None);
        yield return Tuple.Create(objFgr, objCodeFgr);   
    }
}
```

You can enumerate over the collection returned from the fucntion like this:

```
foreach(var pair in GetStuff()){
    //do other stuff here
    Console.WriteLine(string.format("Item1: {0}, Item2: {1}", pair.Item1, pair.Item2));
}
```